# Hyperlink re-directing to a masked URL

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, sendgrid

I am managing an e-mail campaign (containing HTML) for a customer of ours, and I am in the middle of a situation where I can't reproduce what is happening.

When I insert a hyperlink in the message body with the customer's website like : `https://customer.com` and send the campaign through `"SendGrid"` (our delivery service)a user clicks on the hyperlink in their e-mail, then it takes them somewhere completely different, it seems like the URL is masked.

When I then check the HTML source of the e-mail, instead of the link being `https://customer.com` it is `http://https://customer.com`

If I copy paste the URL in the browser then it works fine. If I create an HTML locally with the hyperlink to the customer's website, it still works fine.

Can there be something the customer needs to activate in their end?

Comment: ***then it takes them somewhere completely different, ***
Does it mean finally it redirects to any other URL except https://customer.com?

it seems like the URL is masked.
Yes. Sendgrid does it. But that is not the problem.

Comment: @SaifulAzad. thank you for the reply. Yes, it does take somewhere, in some link but not the customer.com